# Stream.Position doesn't change after call to StreamReader.ReadLineAsync

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, stream

When I create try to read lines like this, Stream.Position changes one time after first call to StreamReader.ReadLineAsync and then doesn't change after any number of calls.

```
var stream = new FileStream(
filename,
FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true);

using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    while(stream.Position <= stream.Length)
    {
        var pos = stream.Position;
        var line = sr.ReadLineAsync().Result;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pos, line);
    }
}
```

When I run this, given input

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
```

It gives me output

```
0: 1 2 3
29: 4 5 6
29: 7 8 9
29: 10 11 12
29: 
29:
```

And so on.

Comment: The async aspect of this is irrelevant, btw - I would strongly expect to see the same behaviour with `ReadLine`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`StreamReader.ReadLine` (and equivalently `ReadLineAsync`) will often read more than *just* a single line - it basically reads into a buffer and then interprets that buffer. That's much more efficient than reading a single byte at a time, but it does mean that the stream will have advanced further than it strictly speaking needs to.

Basically, I wouldn't try to use `Stream.Position` for a stream which is wrapped by another object (e.g. `BufferedStream`, `StreamReader` etc). The buffering *will* make things confusing.

Comment: After reading some sources at referencesource.microsoft.com I've found this comment that describes how to deal with the situation: "DiscardBufferedData tells StreamReader to throw away its internal buffer contents.  This is useful if the user needs to seek on the underlying stream to a known location then wants the StreamReader to start reading from this new point.  This method should be called very sparingly, if ever, since it can lead to very poor performance. However, it may be the only way of handling some scenarios where users need to re-read the contents of a StreamReader a second time."

Comment: @Spo1ler: That doesn't really deal with the situation of misreporting - it doesn't let you find out where the stream would be after reading each stream. It's about starting from a given point for the *next* read from the reader, not for reporting where in the stream it *would* have been if it weren't for the buffer.